# Why are there are no USB 3 over Ethernet devices (aka: USB extenders) on the market?

Tags: ethernet, usb

There are plenty of adapters that transmit USB 1 or 2 protocol over Ethernet cable (marketed as "USB extenders"). But why not an extender for USB 3?

Here is [a typical USB 2 over Cat 6 Ethernet cable extender](https://archive.ph/Hv1uT). Currently they tend to price in the +$100 USD range.

The USB 1 over Cat 5e Ethernet cable [are typically in the $20 USD range](https://archive.ph/mNg4E), a seemingly low price.

Yet USB 3, [which was standardized in 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=USB_3.0&oldid=1065858147), has at this time, January of 2022, no "extender" devices on the market.

Is this because of a technical difficulty of using Ethernet cable to transmit USB 3 protocol?

Or is market demand, compared to already available options (USB 1 and 2 "extenders"), not enough to justify the costs of producing USB 3 "extenders"?

Some other reason?

Comment: I linked to archived versions of the products for sale, so it doesn't seem like I'm trying to advertise (also to avoid web rot).

Comment: You can barely get 10 gigabit Ethernet working over all 8 wires. What makes you think you can transmit 4 times as much over half the wires?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Expand on that comment slightly and that could be an answer. Because it makes the most sense.